# Event Types In Unity Scripting

Tags: unity-game-engine

i just wanna start to codding more clean and dynamic codes and i start to learn "events" but im so confused about events because all videos show different things 0.0 did i understand wrong or there are three types of events ? i mean

- c# event
- unity events
- game events
  if i understand true this all different event systems right ? and i can use which i want, and i should spesific.
  i hope i understand right can someone explain shortly ?  if i understand right just can say yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [UnityEvents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html). Usually `AddListener(YourFunction)`

There are [Unity Events](https://blog.unity.com/news/the-future-of-unite-conferences) (meta, haha!)

There is an official Unity [Tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/events-uh) on C# Events. Usually with the `+=` operator: `.OnClicked += YourFunction;`

There is an [Event System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/EventSystem.html) for the "Unity UI 1.0.0" Package, but there is also still the [old Event System](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html) for Ui/Canvas interaction (until Unity 2018?).

There is the [Event System](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event.html) for UI inside of Unity, if you want to build an Editor Tool, to paint prefabs in the Scene for example.

The "old" Input System (`Input.GetKeyDown("Space")`) is also an [Event System](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html).
But there is also a still optional, new [Input System Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html) that handles local Coop (multiple Controllers) a bit better. You can only use one at a time. (You have to switch form one to the other in Settings)

As you can see, there a a lot of Event Systems. You can write your own, if that is required for a Task. Event Systems are a general way to handle changes without polling and comparing values every frame, but listening to changes and occurances.

Comment: thank you so much than i understand true :D there is really alot of event system thank you for explaining ^^